# Loopback 3 generating auto ids of type string

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am migrating from using `mongodb` to `postgres` in loopback 3. When I was using `mongodb`, auto generated ids were of type string. In case of `postgres`, auto generated id is of type number.

I have gone through the loopback documentation, it says:

> The generated property indicates the ID will be automatically generated by the database. If true, the connector decides what type to use for the auto-generated key. For relational databases, such as Oracle or MySQL, it defaults to number.

So, according to the documentation, for relational databases, default id is of type number. How can I change this default to of type `string`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the id property in the declaration of the model. 
Just check that you have set the **idInjection** property to false. Then, declare a property named "Id" and set the data type you want.
Of course, you should migrate the model again.

Comment: Thanks Petros, I am aware of that, I was hoping to find a solution where I do not have to give my own unique IDs as it would require a lot of effort in changing all the models. Anyway, if no other option is available, I will go ahead with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the defaultFn to setup a default string ID, here is my sample code using uuidv4 to generate random string ID

```
"userId": {
        "type": "string",
        "id": true,
        "length": 36,
        "defaultFn": "uuidv4",
        "dataType": "char"
    }
```